# Problems exporting a table in mysql with INTO OUTFILE in MAC OS

Tags: mysql, into-outfile

I have a MAC OS X with MySQL Community server. I just finished my query and I have one table with 6,000,000 rows and 32 columns.

If I try to select * in the table, the program show me the error

> Error Code: 2008 (mysql client ran out of memory)

I have tried to use INTO OUTFILE but this give me a error too.

> (Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement)

Looking for help in the forum I have found that I have to save the file in the priv_secure_file folder but if I run show variables like 'secure%' I have a NULL value for this.

I have been working in this database for 3 month, I can not found any file like `my.cnf` and if I modify the file `com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`, adding one line with `<string>--secure-file-priv=patstat/raw/</string>` the server does not run.